# How do I download a video from icloud?

Tags: icloud, video

I have a video on my icloud that I want to download to macbookpro and save. I can  see the video in icloud on  my iphone. The video is deleted from iphoto on my iphone and I can't download the video back to my iphone (I can select the video but the icon on bottom left the box with the arrow will not light up). When I log into icloud on macbookpro I can't see any photos or shared streams. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the Video at the Moment? In iCloud Photostream?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the walled-garden guards in Apple don't want to provide any easy way to do it.

Comment: Apple don't provide an easy way. They want to deliberately disappoint their customers and make their lives much harder so we are excited when they fix their poor choices. The easiest way is this cli tool https://github.com/ndbroadbent/icloud_photos_downloader

Answer (score 1):

On your mobile device you open the icloud photo stream by its title, tap on "people", turn on "public website"  then tap "share" and send  the stream to your own email. In your email you will get a link to your photo stream under the title of the stream . When you click on the link from your laptop or desktop you will find a webpage with all items in that stream including your videos. Get a video web downloader add on extension for your browser and you can download the video once you've clicked on it to start. From there you can import it to iphoto and sync it with your iphone photos

Comment: In response to the second recommendation...this does not work. Plugging in the iphone to your laptop/desktop and then opening the DCIM folder to "drag" the video file to your PC did not work for me. The video was shared with me (via iCloud) and showed up in the shared folder...but plugging my phone into the laptop only showed my OWN photos and videos...and not the photos and videos from the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since iCloud can be unreliable, the best method would be to plug in your phone over USB and copy it from there.

Comment: [the app works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggbvi.jpg) Thank you @tetsujin your app worked better than anything else I tired! I was able to finally download some Halloween videos I had saved to the shared albums that I had deleted off my phone because like a dummy I thought the videos were retrievable from the shareable iCloud folder. Thanks so much again!!! Xo

Answer (score 0):

I just use dropbox, videos automatically go into the camera uploads folder. If the video isn't showing up because it already got moved to your icloud click the video and hit edit so that it downloads to your phone then plug back in and it will copy to your dropbox camera uploads folder. It can be a pesky process if it's more than one video, wish there was a quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an app available for iOS that allows downloading of videos, live photos, and pictures from Shared Albums:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shared-album-enhancer/id1266163789?mt=8

Disclosure:  I am the app developer.

Comment: This app just came out today (v1.0).  Are you the app developer?

Comment: @fsb -  the user is new as of today as well.

Comment: KDP, there's nothing wrong with posting an answer with your own software, however, you must disclose your connection to the software.  Per our [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."  Please [edit] your answer to include this affiliation, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You can download videos to your computer from photos. *Preferences > iCloud*

To make your folder a system folder you need to select `Use as System Photo Library` from the General tab. Then it's usable with iCloud.

In my case, I had too many photos in my current photo library so enabling `iCloud Photo Library` lead to Apple forcing me to upgrade. To bypass the upgrade I did the following:

- Create a new Photos library (I called my 'iCloud Library')
- Open the new Library, which is emtpy
- Set new library as the System Library, you can change this later
- Enable `iCloud Photo Library` and set it to `Download Originals to this Mac` (you'll need enough space, I'm using an external)
- After they are all downloaded you can drag them from your iCloud folder to your original Photos folder
- Delete the iCloud folder and set your main library back to the system library

Good luck!